# Как в документе сделать поле выбора из справочника по определенному реквизиту?

Tags: 1с

у меня есть справочник клиенты в нем реквизиты: стандартные(наименование используется как название компании) и ФИО. И есть форма документа где нужно выбрать фио клиента. Как можно реализовать, чтобы не по наименованию список был, а по фио?

Comment: Правильно ли понял, что в поле выбора вы хотите вводить ФИО и чтобы объекты искались по нему?

Comment: @Sagittarius, Да хочу в поле выбора выбирать по фио, а не по наименованию. поиск мне не нужен. У меня создание документа о покупке товара, в доке есть реквизиты: ФИО и стандартные. И в табличной части реквизиты: ТОвар, цена кол-во. Я уже сделал, чтобы при выборе товара вставка производилась по цене. А вот как сделать фио вместо наименования что-то никак не могу додуматься

Comment: А это нужно только в единичном поле выбора реализовать или в множестве?

Comment: @Sagittarius В единственном

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Если реквизит ФИО строкового типа, установить у него свойство "Индексировать" в "Индексировать" или "ИндексироватьСДопУпорядочиванием". После в настройках объекта, на закладке "Поле ввода", в поле "Ввод по строке" добавить ваш реквизит ФИО.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Статья на ИТС](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev#content:2207:hdoc:3.%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9,%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9)

2. Посмотреть в сторону событий менеджера справочника "ОбработкаПолученияДанныхВыбора()". И в нем делать запрос, который будет отбирать элементы именно по ФИО.

[Пример](https://hisoka1c.blogspot.com/2017/02/blog-post_78.html)

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!

Comment: @AvgustKuk, пожалуйста